# Dynamic div content, but need a fixed div height

Tags: javascript, dynamic, height, slide

I'm using javascript to animate a div collapsing/sliding. The javascript requires the div to have a set height, although the content inside the div is dynamic. How would I go about making it work, as I don't want the div to be any larger than it's meant to. I've set the height of the div like this:

```
<div id="main-div" style="overflow:hidden; height:95px;">
```

I've tried setting the height to 'auto' but when the div slides open again, it doesn't slide to the correct height. Would I need to calculate the height?

Comment: I can't set the height myself as the content is dynamic, and will always change. Also setting it to 'auto' still doesn't make the div slide back open to the correct size. So I need a way to calculate the size of the div (in px) and then set the height of the div. That way it's not 'auto' and it still isn't fixed at a certain size. Sorry if I'm still not clear. I'll upload an example to show.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want 'auto' as that means "fit the box height to the content height." Are you saying that setting the height attribute is not working? What is your full div markup?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `min-height` and `max-height` as well.

And I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you have a problem with your current approach? What is that problem?